# Multiple selection with UISegmentedControl - what is Pages using?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to make a Bold/Underline/Italic toolbar like you see on Pages (iPhone/iPad). They use what appears to be a UISegmentedControl.

But they can have both Bold/Underline selected at the same time, which doesn't seem to be possible with the current UISegmentedControl. The closest thing I can find is "momentary", which makes the UISegmentedControl like a button array.

The NSSegmentedControl (Mac version) seems to have this ability by setting [cell setTrackingMode:NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectAny]. It also has NSSegmentSwitchTrackingMomentary, similar to UISegmentedControl (which uses a BOOL).

Is there a way to sub-class the UISegmentedControl to add this ability? Is there any good third party toolbars controls that do this? What Apple's Pages doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `UISegmentedControl`. You may want to create them as separate `UIButtons` and do whatever you wish to them. After all, you are using behavior like `UIButton`s, so it shouldn't be any harder.

Comment: Looks like do-it-yourself is the answer.